# Object Oriented Design for stackoverflow

Tags: object, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to implement an object-oriented design for stack overflow. I have Member, Question, Answer, Comment object. (not considering tags, bounty other objects for simplicity). I am not able to figure out the storage of data in design.

The user creates a question, Answer, Comment with a title and description. I am not able to figure out where I should save the data because these objects belong to the user and global search also. Answer and comment can also happen on any question but they belong to the user also. so the problem is to store the data user-specific and global.

I have a thought process to create a repository that will keep data for questions, answers, and comments. I can store questionsIds, answerIds, commentIds in member object. similarly, anserIds and comments in Question object. I am not sure it's good practice for object-oriented design or not.

```java
    public class Member {
        private long memberId;
        // few more properties
        Member(){
    
        }
        public long createQuestion(String title, String description){ return 1;}
        public long createAnswer(long questionId, String description){ return 1;}
        public long createQuestionComment(long questionId, String description){ return 1;}
        public long createAnswerComment(long answerId, String description){ return 1;}
    }
    
    
    public class Question {
        private long id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        Question(String title, String description){
    
        }
    }
```

In case, you want more details. I will create a UML dig for more explanation. If someone knows about any good article please refer me there. If you know about any good book where I can learn more about the object-oriented approach please let me know that also.

Comment: In case of stackoverflow, you can download a data dump and see how it's actually organized in the real thing: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange. The dump for SO itself is many GBs large and is split into several files, so you can download a dump of a smaller stackexchange site.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to figure out OO design or storage? The two often go hand-in-hand, but not always.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The end goal is to create the OO design. but I stuck in data storage. it's an OO design so I am doing it at the memory level. In short, I am looking for a data storage opinion here. But if you want to refer to OO design of StackOverflow that will also helpful

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I went through the above link. I think the schema design is great but not sure about it in terms of OO design. If you wanna give any opinion it would be great.

Comment: Frankly, not a fan of the suggested API. Off the top of my head, I'd either go with more or less directly replicating the DB schema (`Comment.create(...)`) or wrapping the operations in services (`Services::App::Comment::Create.call(...)`). In the latter case, the `Comment::Create` service can orchestrate writing to the DB, updating caches, sending out notifications and whatnot.

Comment: If your question was "should I also design an in-memory storage backend for this API (in addition to designing the OO API itself)", then it's something I'd clarify with the interviewer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have agreed with you. I am so doubtful during practicing OO design questions. Should I mention service and repository layers or do everything in objects only. In the real world, we have a service layer and a persistence layer. But do you think it's a valid question to ask the interviewer because I think he will say it's up to you. What's your opinion?

Comment: Yes, I'd ask the interviewer what to do with persistence. Should I assume that it's a relational database and "just works" or should I store everything in-memory.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your response. I think it makes sense to ask for the approach because both have a different way of doing it. I think it's good to ask how we are going to use this application also It has API or input from command. I think now it's pretty much clear in my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The storage is a separate issue from how you interact with it.

In a classic SQL setup the `member`, `answer`, `comment`, etc are all separate database tables with numeric id keys.  The relationships are likely one-directional where the `comment` has a `memberId` field, but the `member` would not know anything about the comments.  You would find a member's comments by querying the `comment` table for comments with the correct `memberId`.  [Here's your StackOverflow comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1417879/comments-by-user?UserId=8906489), which we find through the query `SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE UserId = 8906489`.

These classes that you are designing would be used to interact with those database tables and create a local (per page load) cache system.  In terms of the Model-View-Controller pattern the database tables are the Model and these classes are the Controller. Your `Member` class knows its `memberId` so it can create and execute a comments query that selects comments for that id, or that inserts a comment with that member id, etc.

You don't want to have the same data in lots of places so you probably have some sort of central `Repository` class.  When you are calling `createQuestion` on the `Member` that needs to be linked to the `Repository`.  You would either design it so that instances of `Member` get the `Repository` as a constructor argument, or so that all interactions are initiated by the `Repository`, which can pass itself as a function argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have implemented using the repository. Could you please check and let me know if you are thinking in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an OO solution with a repository structure. I have considered simple functionality only. I think we can break the repository into separate repositories like AnswerRepository, QuestionRepository.

**Main:**

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverflow app= new StackOverflow();
        StackOverflowRepository repository = new StackOverflowRepository();
        String memberName = "Vimit"; // assume this as a input  from application
        long memberId = app.registerMember(memberName, repository);
        long questionId = app.createQuestion(repository,memberId, "OO design stackoverflow", "How to do  OO design for stack overflow questions"); // when anymmeber will call we have only member id
        app.createAnswer(repository, "I dont know about OO design", questionId, memberId); // whe  someone call this function, it will be meber and on some squestion so we always have member Id
        app.searchQuestions( "ood", repository);
    }
    public long registerMember(String memberName, StackOverflowRepository repository){
        Member member = new Member(memberName);
        repository.addMember(member);
        return member.getId();
    }
    public long createQuestion(StackOverflowRepository repository, long memberId, String title, String description){
        Member member = repository.getMember(memberId);
        return member.createQuestion(repository, title, description);
    }

    public long createAnswer(StackOverflowRepository repository, String description, long questionId, long memberId){
        Member member = repository.getMember(memberId);
        return member.createAnswer(repository, description,questionId);
    }

    public List<Question> searchQuestions(String searchText, StackOverflowRepository repository){
        return  repository.searchQuestion(searchText);
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class StackOverflowRepository {
    private AtomicLong memberId;
    private AtomicLong questionId;
    private AtomicLong answerId;
    private Map<Long, Member> members;
    private Map<Long, Question> questions;
    private Map<Long, Answer> answers;
    private Map<String, List<Long>> searchQuestions; // reverseIndex for question search

    StackOverflowRepository() {
        memberId = new AtomicLong(0);
        questionId = new AtomicLong(0);
        members = new HashMap<>();
        questions = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Question addQuestion(long memberId, Question question){
        question.setId(questionId.incrementAndGet());
        questions.put(questionId.get(), question);
        members.get(memberId).addQuestionId(questionId.get());
        createReverseIndex(question);
        return question;
    }

    public long addMember(Member member) {
        member.setId(memberId.incrementAndGet());
        members.put(memberId.get(), member);
        return memberId.get();
    }

    public Member getMember(long memberId){
        return members.get(memberId);
    }

    public List<Question> searchQuestion(String search){
        String[] words = search.split("//s");
        List<Long> questionIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String word: words){
            questionIds.addAll(searchQuestions.get(word));
        }
        return questionIds.stream().distinct().map(id -> questions.get(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public long addAnswer(Answer answer,  long memberId, long questionId){
        answer.setId(answerId.incrementAndGet());
        answers.put(answerId.get(), answer);
        members.get(memberId).addAnswerId(answerId.get());
        questions.get(memberId).addAnswerId(answerId.get());
        return  answer.getId();
    }

    private void createReverseIndex(Question question){
        String[] words = question.getDescription().split("//s");
        for(String word: words){
            List<Long> ids = searchQuestions.getOrDefault(word, new ArrayList<>());
            ids.add(question.getId());
            searchQuestions.put(word, ids);
        }

    }

}
```

**Member:**

```
public class Member {
    private long id;
    private String memberName;
    private List<Long> questionIds;
    private List<Long> answerIds;
    Member(String memberName){
        this.memberName = memberName;
    }

    public long createQuestion(StackOverflowRepository stackOverflowRepository, String title, String description){
        Question question = new Question(title, description);
        stackOverflowRepository.addQuestion(this.id,question);
        return question.getId();
    }

    public long createAnswer(StackOverflowRepository stackOverflowRepository, String description, long questionId){
        Answer answer = new Answer(description);
        return stackOverflowRepository.addAnswer(answer, this.id, questionId);
    }


    public void addQuestionId(long id){
        this.questionIds.add(id);
    }

    public void setId(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void addAnswerId(long id) {
        answerIds.add(id);
    }
}
```

**Question:**

```
public class Question {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private List<Long> answerIds;
    Question(String title, String description){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void addAnswerId(long id) {
        this.answerIds.add(id);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

**Answer:**

```
public class Answer {
    private Long id;
    private String description;

     Answer(String description) {
         this.description = description;
    }

    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```